# PRESTASHOP 8 how to redirect to product edit page after handling post request in front controller of module

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-modules

I have o module `mymodule` - that is hooked in product edit page in BO.
It has a form. Submitting form sends data to front controller:

```html
<form action="{Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'default')}" method="post">
```

Controller handles POST requests - and I need it to redirect to BO product edit page after that.
I am trying to use something like that:

```php
$openTab = 3; 
$url = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminProducts', true, ['id_product' => $product_ID]); 
$url .= '#tab-step'.$openTab;

Tools::redirect($url);
```

and is not working, the part with `getAdminLink`. I got the `$this->context` and `Tools::redirect('')` also works fine. `$product_ID` has a value.

I am missing something.
Any tips?